# Как сделать маленькую карту гугл на свой сайт?

Tags: карты, google-maps-api

Мне нужно чтобы шириной она была 135 а высотой 70. Но в итоге выходит вот это безобразие: [image]

Может как-то еще можно, в том смысле что мешает много чего, а саму карту не видно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте JavaScript API, в нём есть возможность полностью контролировать управляющие элементы. [Например](http://blog.aaa-nan.info/2010/08/google-maps-api-3_07.html).